# For loop Arduino, access all positions in array

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

Hi I am starting to study about Arduino and I would like some help.

I wrote this loop but when I go to see it Serial Monitor, it keeps on repeating endlessly.

How could I make the loop go through this array and stop after going through all the positions?

```cpp
int x1[4];
    
void setup() {
  x1[0] = 0;
  x1[1] = 0;
  x1[2] = 1;
  x1[3] = 1;
      
  Serial.begin(9600); 

  for (byte i = 0; i < sizeof(x1); i++) {
    Serial.println(".." + sizeof(x1));
  }
}
    
void loop() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several points to address:

1. Your main code should run inside the `loop()`.
2. By using some simple logic, you can run the print inside the loop only once
3. This will NOT print the elements from the array. Why do you use sizeof(x1) as an argument in the `Serial.println` function?

> 

```
for (byte i = 0; i < sizeof(x1); i++) 
{
        Serial.println(".." + sizeof(x1));
}
```

> 

Here's an idea:

```
#define ELEMENTS 4

int x1[4];

bool printDone;    // Boolean flag for printing once

// Setup() should only be used for initializations

void setup(){

    // Always start the serial port first
    Serial.begin(9600);
    
    // Fill your array --> consider using a loop, if possible
    x1[0] = 0;
    x1[1] = 0;
    x1[2] = 1;
    x1[3] = 1;
    
    // Initialize your flag
    printDone = false;
}

// Main functionalities from your code go inside the loop()

void loop(){
    
    if (printDone == false){

        for(byte i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++){
            Serial.println(x1[i]);
        }

        printDone = true;    // When you are done, raise the flag
    
    }

 }
```

Comment: I used sizeof no for to see the size of the array.

Thank you for showing me how I should have written.